# RaphaelJS hide shape onmouseout

Tags: raphael, onmouseover, onmouseout

I've created 4 rects using for loop. If you hover on any of these rects a rect will be displayed alongside. But the problem is that newly displayed rect doesn't hide on mouse out. What is wrong with my code?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TL78u/21/)

```
window.onload = function() {
var paper = Raphael(0, 0, 640, 540);    

function aa(h1,h2){
    var showbox = paper.rect(h1+300,h2,100,100);
}
function ab(){
    showbox.hide();
}

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        (function(i, j) {
            var boxes = paper.rect(0 + (j * 100), 0 + (i * 100), 100, 100).attr({
                fill: '#303030',
                stroke: 'white'
            });
            boxes.node.onmouseover = function() {
                var h1 = boxes.getBBox().x;
                var h2 = boxes.getBBox().y;
                aa(h1,h2);
            };

            boxes.node.onmouseout = function() {
                ab();
            };
        })(i, j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got javascript scope problems (plus two other smaller problems, see below).

The variable `showbox` is defined within function `aa`. So your onmouseout function can't see it. Get Firebug or your browser's equivalent up and you'll see a stack of `showbox is not defined` errors.

**Tip:** When working with Raphael, I usually create an object or array that contains all my created objects, keyed for easy access and scoped above all my Raphael-related functions so all of them can access it (see jsfiddle example below).

How to access your Raphael objects is a piece of application design you need **to decide on early on**, else you'll need to do lots of refactoring further down the line (been there, it hurts!).

Here's an adapted version of your code that works:

### [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TL78u/23/)

Edit: I added comments explaining each change.

---

It also fixes **two other problems**:

- (In the jsfiddle code) No such `attr` as `display: none;` in Raphael, try `.attr({opacity:0})` or `.hide()`...
- ...BUT... don't! Your mouseover event creates rectangles, your mouseout event... *hides* them...? You're going to have an ever-growing stack of invisible rectangles that could eventually crash someone's browser. Either show, then hide, or create, then remove - don't create then hide!

The mouseover / mouseout events themselves are actually fine! :-)

Comment: thanks for explaining it so well :) I wont be making those mistakes again.